Can その be used as a possesive pronoun?
I know この、その、あの and どの are all noun modifiers, are roughly an equivalent of "this (thing), that (thing) that (thing) over there, which (thing)" and are used to convey a sense of distance of the subject being talked about and the listener/speaker.
Now, can その mean the same as "his" or "her"? I came across the following sentence while reading Doraemon:

のび太にそっくり！はたしてそのしょうたいは？


I assume the translation would be following "Nobita's look-alike! What's his true identity?" (please correct me if I'm wrong)
The use of その here is kinda weird to me, mostly because it would sound weird in english if translated as "that". So my doubt here is what would be the difference here between adding that その and omitting it, is there some kind of nuance?

How the その works
You are correct on how to interpret the sentence.
What may feel odd to you is likely because "その" can refer not only to something explicitly mentioned, but also to something implied in the context. Here are some example:

ある教授の話を聞いた。その教授は田中という。 -- I listened to a professor. His name is Tanaka. (Here, "その" refers to "教授" (professor)  mentioned explicitly in the previous sentence..)
ある教授の話を聞いた。その研究はとても高度だった。 -- I listened to a professor. His research was quite advanced. (Here, "その" refers to 研究(research), implied through the context of "教授" (professor).)
ある教授の話を聞いた。その車はとても速い。(This sounds odd) -- I listened to a professor. The car is very fast. (This does not make sense, as there is no mention or implication of a car(車).)

Now, with this understanding, let's look at how "その" works in your question:

のび太にそっくり！はたしてそのしょうたいは？

The first sentence "のび太にそっくり"(Nobita's look-alike) naturally leads people to wonder, "Who is this?" In this way, the sentence implicitly introduces the concept of "しょうたい" (true identity), making "その" appropriate.
with and without その
Now, let's compare the sentences with and without その:

のび太にそっくり！はたしてそのしょうたいは？
のび太にそっくり！はたしてしょうたいは？

Both versions convey a similar meaning and nuance, but the one without その feels a big ambiguous. With その, the sentence is clearer about what it refers to, and I believe most people would find it more comfortable and natural to read.
